# How do you log to the error console from untrusted Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Chromium, 'console.log()' lets you print to the error console, but only from javascript embedded in the html, or in a .js file on the local machine.

What are your workarounds for debugging Javascript that is contained in .js files on a remote machine and included in a page?

Comment: Really? I've never noticed any problems logging from remote scripts.

Comment: @sje397 I knew it! what browser have you been debugging with?

Comment: @sje397 I think Nathan means hosted third party scripts

Comment: @Phil: I think it still works in that case.

Comment: @Nathan: Chrome...I'm gonna have to test this out :)

Comment: @icktoofay Kind of hard to write `console.log()` statements into a third party script though. My guess is Nathan is not aware of the debugging capabilities in Chromium

Comment: OK.. I wrote a simple test, and it appears to work... derp. http://nathannifong.com/test/jslogtest/jstest.html

Comment: Problem is not with console.log, and my previous statement is just false. voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoints and / or watch expressions.

See http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this with a Facebook SDK javascript, hosted by Facebook. I downloaded the script and hosted it locally for debugging. I could then add in all the console.log messages I wanted.

When everything was done I removed the local file and returned to Facebook's hosted script.

Phil's suggestion of breakpoints is also very useful when you want the value of a variable at a specific location in the code.

---

Another useful technique for code executed upon a user action, such as a button click, is to use the Scripts tab of the Chrome inspector, or FireBug in FF, to edit the javascript prior to execution. I've had limited use for this, but it's quite useful from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is cross-domain security policy. Only javascript from the domain of the html file can use console.log